# How can I shift all keys one position forward from a starting and end point in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array like this:

```
 [
        543 => 1,
        22  => 3,
        65  => 4,
        10  => 5,
        50  => 6,
    ]
```

Now I get a key and a value as input. For example 22 as key and 5 as value.

Now I want to use those two inputs as start and end point in my array and want to shift all keys one forward between those two positions.

```
 [
    543 => 1,
    22  => 3,  ─┐                                      ┌─  65 => 3,
    65  => 4,   ├ Shift all those keys one forward to: ┤   10  => 4,
    10  => 5,  ─┘                                      └─  22  => 5,
    50  => 6,
]
```

So the expected output would be:

```
   [
        543 => 1,
        65 => 3,
        10 => 4,
        22=> 5,
        50  => 6,
    ]
```

Comment: I don't quite see what the pattern here is. You change the keys `22`, `65`, `10` to `65`, `10`, `22`. Where is the pattern? Also where are you stuck at doing it?

Comment: @Rizier123 Looks like every other key just shifts upward to fill it in. I think you'll have to write a custom function for this.

Comment: @larsAnders I know what you mean, that `22 => X` is kinda like the start point and `X => 5` the end point and he wants to shift all keys one forward, but I'm really not sure if this is what OP means.

Comment: How will the user change the position? I mean they will visually update anything, like sort any data/info?

Comment: Basically the concept is when user want to change value for position 22 to 5 then array should be print like given second one array.

Comment: @Meathanjay basically the order will change as per the text input like when user will open page for id 22 the current order is shown on textbox and there is option for update it

Comment: @user2110253 So you get a key and a value as input? Also when you have multiple same values, which one should be used? As an example if you have: `key = b; value = 5` and array `[a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 5, e => 6]` the expected output would be: `[a => 1, d => 2, b => 3, c => 5, e => 6]` right?

Comment: @Rizier123 you are right please tell me how  can do this

Comment: @user2110253 1) And which value do you use when you have multiple of the same values? Do you just use the next one after the key or what? 2) Have you tried something to achieve this?

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for editing exactly what i need please also help me ut to resolved it

Comment: @user2110253 My last comment still remains. If you have `[a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 2];` And you have `key = c` and `value = 2` as input, which value do you use? The first one and use that one as start point? Or the one after the key c and use that as end point?

Answer (score 2):

Figure out the start and end offset from your inputs in your array:

```
$startIndex = array_search(22, array_keys($arr));
$endIndex   = array_search(5 , array_values($arr));
                         //↑ Your input
```

So for your example array this would look like this:

```
[
    543 => 1,  //Offset: 0
    22  => 3,  //Offset: 1 ← 22 found; offset: 1
    65  => 4,  //Offset: 2
    10  => 5,  //Offset: 3 ←  5 found; offset: 3
    50  => 6,  //Offset: 4
]
```

Split your array into three parts:

```
$before = array_slice($arr, 0, $startIndex, true);
$data   = array_slice($arr, $startIndex, ($endIndex - $startIndex) + 1, true);
$after  = array_slice($arr, $endIndex, null, true);
```

Visualized this would look like this:

```
[
    543 => 1,  → $before; Where you do NOT want to shift your keys
    22  => 3,  ┐
    65  => 4,  ├ $data; Where you want to shift your leys
    10  => 5,  ┘
    50  => 6,  → $after; Where you do NOT want to shift your keys
]
```

Rotate the data part keys, just by merging the last key at the start with the other keys at the end:

```
$keys = array_keys($data);
$keys = array_merge(array_slice($keys, -1), array_slice($keys, 0, -1));
$data = array_combine($keys, $data);
```

Put it all back together:

```
$arr = $before + $data + $after;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but when i print the output after implementing your code the array result is same as it is defined first. so please tell me where i am wrong

Comment: @Rizier Got distracted in a conference call, thanks for the fixes.

Comment: no problem. (@user2110253 The answer should work for you now, check it again)

Comment: That's great this works thank you so much but one question more in the situation where we want to change order in increment type but when suppose I want to change order for position 50 to 1 then this code is not working any idea for this.

Comment: @user You need to ensure that the start index is lower than the end index. Test for that and swap them around if necessary.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for information but hen it is not lower then how i will mange it.

Comment: @user Not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @deceze I am asking that when i want to change key 50 to 1 then the order  should be [50]=>1 543=>3 22=>4 ... and so on so how i will do coz this code is not support for that

Comment: @user Again: just ensure the start index is lower than the end index. Added an augmented sample here: https://3v4l.org/sQmnr

Comment: Thanks @deceze your code is absolutely right you are really genious

Comment: @deceze one last question the answer which you given and Rizer modified it is not getting exact output which you did it right now with link coz the output for changing 22 value to 6 output should be 543=>1 65=>3 10=>4 50=>5 22=>6  please if it possible can you tell me that also

Comment: @user I have no idea where that logic comes from, that seems counter to anything else before. At some point you will simply have to *understand* the code sample and adjust it to your situation as necessary.

Comment: Ok @deceze thanks for your supprt

Comment: @deceze if it is possible lease check the question above now i corrected the array can you suggest me to solve this,it would be really very very thankful to you.